# show overlay on flexslider control thumb hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

im trying to customize the flexslider (http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html) in a way that when a user hovers on a navigation thumbnail to show an overlay with an icon. Something like this http://callmenick.com/_development/image-overlay-hover-effects/

by editing the flexslider js code i managed to add a div

```
<div class="thumb_overlay"></div><img src="'+s.attr("data-thumb")+'"'+c+"/>":'<a href="#">'+t+"</a>"
```

but i couldnt move it to above the image although i set relative positions

http://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/r4uthech/1/

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your CSS:

```
.flex-control-nav li{
    position: relative;
}
.flex-control-nav li img{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.flex-control-nav li:hover img{
    opacity: .5;
}
.flex-control-nav li::after{
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    background-image: url(//i.imgur.com/xMS5K4O.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 40px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
}
.flex-control-nav li:hover::after{
    top: 0;  
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
}
```

If you prefer, here is your fiddle updated:

http://jsfiddle.net/r4uthech/2/

I hope this can help you. :)

Comment: Perfect... Thanks alot :)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to choose this answer as the right one ✔ :)